# Google C2DM servers

Tags: android, android-c2dm

As far as I know, Google C2DM servers gives notifications from third party server. Is it possible to make Google C2DM servers your host for data. Can one send data from an android application to Google C2DM servers for other users of the same application to receive notification of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, yes (as per Piyush's answer), but I would strongly not recommend it. Firstly, each instance of your app would have to have access to your private authentication credentials (which are now at risk of being comprimised). Secondly, if you wanted to update these credentials, you would have to update every installation (ie all of your users) simultaneously or there would be communication issues.

Instead, I would advise getting a free "google app engine" account, and doing broadcast comms through that channel (or any other cloud based provider). You'll be able to keep your keys safe and centrally controlled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible you have to first OAuthenticate your self with Google using registration key, what your application have got from the C2DM server side. For more information see [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html#sourcecode) Tutorial where you can see how we can set up our local server code in an application to send messages. For first register your application on Google C2DM server using google [registration link](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html) here.